# GRE Math Resources

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, advice

I am planning to give the MATH GRE. I intend to go to physics graduate schools but I may have to given the MATH GRE according to my college's requirement. I very much like maths, but I'm overloaded with physics related work, including the GRE, since I have been making a transition from economics/maths to physics/maths.

What are the essential tips for someone like me looking to prepare for the GRE? What books should I go through for each topic?

Comment: First of all, you mean that you're planning to *take* (not give) the Math GRE.  Second, I would need more specific information: which math classes have you taken, for instance?

Comment: There are several questions (with answers) about the math subject area test of the GRE at [Academia StackExchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=GRE+mathematics) that should be helpful.

Comment: $Omnomnonom. I have take Calculus I, II, Linear Algebra, Analysis I, Analysis II, Topology and a course in proof writing in maths. My major focus is on physics but if I had to take the Math GRE for one reason or the other, what'd be the best way to go about it? I absolutely love math and I hope I had taken more classes/if given the time, I'd most definitely want to go through all math textbooks in detail.

Comment: @Ethan Isn't that someone else? Are you confusing the editor with the asker?

Comment: @Deepak Indeed. Sorry. Deleting my comment.